# Angular testing if component method is called during ngOninit?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngoninit

My goal is to create spys of certain methods and check that the methods were called during ngOninit and if pagePurpose equals Update. Currently Im trying to setup the spys and set the component property in the describe and then trying to assert if the functions were called but I get : *Expected spy createLineReviewRequest to have been called*. I feel like Im creating the spys but not using them properly. I need to do this with the highlight method as well, notice that for my case I dont care what the methods were passed.

My Component is as follows :

```
export class ReportsModalLineReviewComponent implements OnInit {
  
  pagePurpose: string;
  canContinue: boolean ;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   
    if (this.pagePurpose === "Update" ) {
      this.highlight(this.dialogData.oldReport.lineReviewRequest.lineReviewFile.fileId)
      this.createLineReviewRequest(this.dialogData.oldReport.lineReviewRequest.lineReviewFile);
      this.canContinue = true;
    }
  }
```

Mt Test is as follows :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReportsModalLineReviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.pagePurpose = "Update";
    spyOn(component, 'createLineReviewRequest');

    fixture.detectChanges();
 });

fit('should check if Update', () => {
    
    expect(component.createLineReviewRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: const spy = spyOn(component, 'createLineReviewRequest'); expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: Don't spy on the thing you're trying to test. Test what e.g. `this. createLineReviewRequest(...)` is supposed to *do*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  that makes sense to me, so I took a step back and tried to assert :      expect(component.canContinue).toBeTruthy(); to see if Im making into the if statement for testing, and I get Expected undefined to be truthy. Im not sure why its undefined.

Comment: I'm surprised TypeScript even lets you do that, `ReportsModalLineReviewComponent` doesn't define a `canContinue` prop.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to include it when I pasted the code, thats on me.

Answer (score 0):

The onInit needs to be called manually

I suggest to follow a convention to make unit testing. **GIVEN -> WHEN -> THEN**

```js
let component: ReportsModalLineReviewComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReportsModalLineReviewComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ReportsModalLineReviewComponent]
  }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReportsModalLineReviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
 });

fit('should check if Update', () => {
    // GIVEN
    component.pagePurpose = "Update";
    spyOn(component, 'createLineReviewRequest');

    // WHEN
    component.ngOnInit()

    // THEN
    expect(component.createLineReviewRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: This approach makes sense to me, but it is not working in my case. I am defining in my describe the component and fixture as such :  let component: ReportsModalLineReviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReportsModalLineReviewComponent>;  in my case I do no use the "this" keyword to access them.

Comment: ohh. I will update my answare without this keyword... Maybe did you configure the testbed? Check my answare again

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody might encounter this issue:

> Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function.

In order to solve it, I changed

**This:**

```
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**To This:**

```
const spy = spyOn(component,'someMethod');
component.ngOnInit();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```